# Is there no fourth dimension (time) in the universe?

Tags: spacetime, time, spacetime-dimensions

In this article (and numerous others) http://phys.org/news/2011-04-scientists-spacetime-dimension.html and http://www.rebelscience.org/Crackpots/notorious.htm they suggest that there is no time dimension and even in the last one that there is no motion in space-time. Do you believe these theories, are they true?

Comment: I don't see any difference between the "numerical order" in your first link and the usual concept of time

Answer (score 2):

Humans have been trying to figure out what time is since we were first able to think about it.  The ideas of Sorli, *et al.* (your first link) are another attempt.  No one knows if they are right or wrong.  I don't think anyone really has a good intuition about what it means to say that "time is a forth dimension", despite being able to use the concept in practice.  Some day we may have a better way of understanding things, and perhaps Sorli is a step down the right path.

Nothing moves in spacetime?  I suppose that's true.  In spacetime we usually speak of "events", and which event occurs before or after which other event to different users.  But I *can* verify that in the 3D spatial world that I occupy, motion does occur.